# Resource file not found in jar but present when opening in winrar

Tags: java

I want to read a json file in my java application which uses gradle. When I run the application in Intellij and gradle run it works fine, but when I do gradle dist and run that jar it throws a FileNotFound. If I open the jar with winrar I see the file in the correct directory.

I have tried getting the file in all ways I could find, some are:

```
new FileReader("data/user-data.json");
new FileReader(new File(getClass().getResource("data/user-data.json").getFile()));
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("data/user-data.json")));
```

and lots more.

Can anyone help me? Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add '/' to the resource path:

```
getResourceAsStream("/data/user-data.json")
```

Your jar should look like this:

```
root (*.jar)
 |-- data
      |-- user-data.json
```

Comment: That works for my jar, but not in Intellij or gradle run